# unknown directive "real_ip_recursive" with module already installed

Tags: nginx

Hi I am new to nginx I am tying to use the mpdule http_realip_module with similar configuration . But when I add the "real_ip_recursive on;" on restarting nginx it gives me error :- nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "real_ip_recursive"

```
set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.2.1;
set_real_ip_from  2001:0db8::/32;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

The module is added i checked with nginx -v it gave me out put as follow which shows nginx :

```
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-E
```

Comment: What is your Nginx version? The real_ip_recursive directive was only added in 1.2.1.